# Terraform: Pass only a variable which was used, to a template file

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I need to render a template depending on a which variable (from a set of always existing, pre-defined variables) ends up being used when the resource is being called.

Examples:

variables.tf

```
possible_choice    = "this" 
another_choice     = "that"
yet_another_choice = "then"
```

main.tf

```
resource "instance" "this_name" {
image_id = var.possible_choice
user_data   = templatefile( "my_template_file.tpl", {choice = image_id})
}
```

template file:

```
%{ if choice == ....) %{endif}
```

What I cannot accomplish is passing the value of the variable which was chosen to be implemneted in the resource.

- I can't check if a variable is null (because they are all defined in variables.tf and will return a string).
- I can't pass `instance.this_name` because the naming is not uniform (it could be either of `this_name.possible_choice` and so on).

If could extract whichever default value is contained within `instance.this_name.image_id`, then I should be good to go, I'd assume. I've tried multiple ways but mostly got `cannot refer to itself`, which makes sense.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `{choice = image_id}` rather then `{choice = var.possible_choice}`?

Comment: I could use `var.possible_choice` but then, per deployment I'll need to know which of the three was indeed used in each specific main.tf . This detail is not a constant and each one of the three choices may be used in each main.tf (but only one of them).  That is why I need to find a programmatic way of knowing which one of the three was indeed used in main.tf and then pass it to the template.

Comment: For example when I use `{choice = image_id}` I get `A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
access, specifying the resource name.
`

Answer (score 0):

Per your requirements, why not implicitly move the choice into its own variable?

```
possible_choice    = "this" 
another_choice     = "that"
yet_another_choice = "then"
actual_choice      = var.WHATEVER_CHOICE_IT_IS

resource "instance" "this_name" {
image_id = var.actual_choice
user_data   = templatefile( "my_template_file.tpl", {choice = var.actual_choice})
}
```

You're just keeping track of the actual choice in its own variable and passing that into the resource itself.

Comment: This could be the only way out, yes. I was trying to avoid that extra step, and somewhat hoping there's a nice trick I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Sadly, terraform can have a bunch of circular dependencies that doesn’t seem obvious. Since the instance hasn’t been created and the resource itself requires one of its own attributes to create it (needed in the template file), it becomes circular.

Comment: That seems to be the case, yes. Well, at least I know I'm not missing on a solution, thank you. I did notice feature requests for something like `self.value` on terraform's github pages. I hope they will implement this sooner than later.